# Effect of Rear Derailleur Cage Length

Tags: gears

What effect does the length of the cage on a rear derailleur have on bike setup/shifting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  cage length is what determines the rear dérailleur’s total capacity. The total capacity equates to how much slack chain the dérailleur can handle. Sheldon calculates it as

```
(number of teeth on largest rear sprocket - number of teeth on smallest rear sprocket)     
+ (number of teeth on largest front chaining - number of teeth on smallest front chaining).
```

On my hybrid I have an 11 - 34 cassette on the back giving a difference of 23, and a 48-38-28 set of chainings on the front giving me a difference of 20. This means I need a rear dérailleur with a cage capable of dealing with a total capacity of 43.

Sheldon's page about dérailleur selection is here: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailleur.html

There is also a capacity measurement given with dérailleurs which equates to the largest sprocket size it can cope with in terms of the number of teeth.